# Should google-kubernetes tag be renamed to kubernetes only?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Kubernetes is a community project now. Would it make sense to rename the tag to [kubernetes](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, that sounds reasonable.  Done.